# need to store files in root folder

Tags: android

i have an application to store files in root folder. do i need to to check the status of the root folder?? amd how can i store files in the root folder???

Comment: guys, it is an android application

Answer (score 0):

> how can i store files in the root folder?

I *think* you can write to the root folder if your phone itself is rooted and your application runs as root. Otherwise, you cannot do this.

Comment: what you mean by "application runs as root"?? am new to android... please help me..

Comment: If you don't know what running applications as root means, you should probably forget the idea about storing data in root folder. Why don't use applications data folder or sdcard instead?